# how to use process id given by one process into another process using c#

Tags: c#

Suppose there is a exe or process which finds process id of newly start process i have to use that pid in some other program but the main problem is that the process that finds pid has while(true ) loop. i.e infinite loop so i cant return any value from it. is there any solution .if yes then please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about writing the PID that you find to some common external storage like a

1. File in a common location accessible by both programs
2. Database table accessible by both programs.